# Switch case in C

Tags: gcc

Can someone help with the below

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    char receive_buff [] ={0x01,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00};

    switch( receive_buff[0] ) 
    {
        case 0x00:
            {printf("\nswitch 00\n");}
        case 0x01:
            {printf("\nswitch 01\n");}
        case 0x02:
            {printf("\nswitch 02\n");}
        default :
            {printf("\nswitch default\n");}
    }
}
```

the result is

```
 ./a.out 

switch 01
Ro
switch 02

switch default
```

I don't know what going on here.

Comment: `main ()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Could You explain what is `Ro`?

Answer (score 6):

```
switch( receive_buff[0] ) 
{
    case 0x00:
        {printf("\nswitch 00\n");}
    case 0x01:
        {printf("\nswitch 01\n");}
    case 0x02:
        {printf("\nswitch 02\n");}

    default :
        {printf("\nswitch defualt\n");}
}
```

Should be

```
switch( receive_buff[0] ) 
{
    case 0x00:
        {printf("\nswitch 00\n");}
        break;
    case 0x01:
        {printf("\nswitch 01\n");}
        break;
    case 0x02:
        {printf("\nswitch 02\n");}
        break;
    default :
        {printf("\nswitch defualt\n");}
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a `break` statement after each set of actions, or the C switch will fall through.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_D.2C_Java.2C_PHP.2C_ActionScript.2C_JavaScript